# podman - How to Start a Process in a Containerfile?

Tags: process, podman, rootless

I have put a script with an endless loop inside a Containerfile.
When I go inside the container and run that script in the background I can see that the process is running by doing a `ps -ef`.
But when I try to start the process inside the `Containerfile` it is not running, even though the `podman build` and `podman run` commands are without error.

I am using rootless `podman`.

This is my `Containerfile`:

```
$ cat Containerfile 
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add vim
RUN apk add bash

COPY ./useless_process.sh /home
RUN bash /home/useless_process.sh &

# how to build:
# podman build . -t "manualpihimage"
# how to run:
# podman run -it --name "manualpihcontainer" manualpihimage
```

I have also tried using the `CMD` and the `ENTRYPOINT` commands but the process did **not** start.

The expectation was that the process would run in the background.

Comment: Does the container show as running or not? `podman ps -a`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried it with Containerfile as follows. Note that I removed the useless `&` - makes no sense in the context of the container and used `CMD` because we don't want to run it while building the image but when we start the container.

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk update
RUN apk add vim
RUN apk add bash

COPY ./useless_process.sh /home
CMD bash /home/useless_process.sh
```

I created useless_process.sh with:

```
#!/bin/sh
while `/bin/true`; do
    date
    sleep 1
done
```

Then `podman build . -t=image1` and `podman run -d --name=container1 image1` to start it detached.

```
$ podman ps -a
CONTAINER ID  IMAGE                            COMMAND               CREATED         STATUS             PORTS                    NAMES
0744f29bec7c  localhost/image1:latest          /bin/sh -c bash /...  22 seconds ago  Up 23 seconds ago                           container1
```

And we can see our useless process is running

```
$ podman exec -it container1 /bin/sh
/ # ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
    1 root      0:00 bash /home/useless_process.sh
  188 root      0:00 /bin/sh
  197 root      0:00 sleep 1
  198 root      0:00 ps
```

Comment: So does that mean that you cannot put a process in the background of a container?
And how is it possible to do a `ps` inside a container when there is a process running in the foreground?

Comment: What do you think "background" means in terms of a container? The container is supposed to have a "primary" process and when that process exits the container stops. You can attach an interactive terminal to that process' STDIN and STDOUT but it you can only meaningfully talk about foreground and background with respect to your terminal. The container itself is just a namespace for processes, devices, networks etc and you can run more processes in that namespace (like I did with `/bin/sh`) with the right commands.